# Function with a data frame column name as input in R

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the best way to nest a function operation on a data frame in another function? I want to write a function which takes a data frame and a column name and then does something on that column and returns the modified data frame like below:

```r
library(dplyr)

func = function(df, col){
  
  df = df %>% mutate(col = col + 1)
  return(df)
}


new_df = func(cars, 'speed')
```

But this raises an error because col is not a string in the function and I am not sure how to replace it with a function input argument other than strings. Any idea how to fix this with minimum effort?

Comment: Your function can be simplified by removing `df =` and `return(df) `.

Comment: Did you change  `func(cars, speed)` into `func(cars, 'speed')`? This needs a slightly different solution.

Comment: it doesn't matter I am happy with both as long as it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `dplyr` code in function you have to use non-standard evaluation. In this case using `{{}}` in the function would do.

```
library(dplyr)

func = function(df, col) {
  
  df = df %>% mutate({{col}} := {{col}} + 1)
  return(df)
}
new_df = func(cars, speed)
head(cars)

#  speed dist
#1     4    2
#2     4   10
#3     7    4
#4     7   22
#5     8   16
#6     9   10

head(new_df)

#  speed dist
#1     5    2
#2     5   10
#3     8    4
#4     8   22
#5     9   16
#6    10   10
```

You can read more about non-standard evaluation here https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Also the usage of `:=` instead of `=` is noteworthy. 

Comment: what if you want the function to plot something using that modified col afterwards instead of returning the df. e.g. hist(df$col)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that you want col to be numeric? so that you can `+ 1`. If that is correct see below.

```
library(dplyr)

func = function(df, col){
  
  df = df %>% mutate(col = as.numeric(col) + 1)
  return(df)
}


new_df = func(cars, 'speed')
```

Another alternative would be to use the index of the column name as the function argument, instead of the string name of the column.

That might look something like

```
library(dplyr)

func = function(df, col_index){
  
  col_name <- colnames(df)[col_index]

  df = df %>% mutate(col_name = col_name + 1)
  return(df)
}


new_df = func(cars, 2)
```